# 3.7V Li-Ion battery powered LED step-up/boost driver

Tags: led, power-electronics, lithium-ion, boost, step-up

Most quality COB LEDs are driven with around 35V. Are there any quality constant current step-up drivers available that allow a 3.7V Li-Ion battery to be used?

Or would I have to use TI's WEBENCH POWER DESIGNER to obtain a circuit, source the components, and solder it myself?

I am not a circuit designer, so any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I think I want to attempt building the circuit myself, so hopefully that re-validates the question. I have found the IC LT3477 from Analog Devices that seems to accept 3.7V Li-Ion input and can step up/boost to 35V. I hope I understood the data sheet correctly. Please see a sample schematic below.

Which components would I need to change to obtain 180mA or 360mA constant current? I saw from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/335325/207467 that there is a "feedback" or "sense" resistor that apparently needs to change with respect to the IC's reference voltage.

[image]

**Edit 2**

Another alternative I found to devise my own circuit is the TPS61169 http://www.ti.com/product/tps61169?qgpn=tps61169 with max. 400mA, where the current is adjusted via an "external sensor resistor". How would I calculate that resistor's value to drive a 90mA, 180mA or 360mA LED? If I knew how that is to be done, I could build my circuit with that part.

**Edit 3**

An even better solution turned out to be the TI LM3410 as a SEPIC device, as shown in the documentation under 8.1.2. That works well with a 3.7V Li-Ion battery as it discharges from 4.2V down to 2.9V with the LED Vf in between - and that little inexpensive IC also boosts 3.7V well to 9V without too much heat, so many other LEDs come into range.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about off-the-shelf product recommendations is off-topic here. If you want to ask about designing the circuit, that is fine but you should edit your question.

Comment: Yeah, that's why the second part of my question was about using TI's WEBENCH, but I am no circuit designer; for many decades, I assembled luminaires from off-the-shelf components, but I am not sure if I should attempt designing the component in question, although I'd like to. The problem is where to start ; )

Comment: This question can be salvaged if you ask specific questions about the **DESIGN** of a suitable converter.  Please do **NOT** ask for recommendations of any particular device - this will cause the question to be closed.

Comment: That's what the second part of the question and my above comment pertains to. How should I go about designing such a thing? I have put in my parameters (input 3.2-4.2V from a Li-Ion battery, output 32-37V to LED) in TI's WEBENCH and am shown two suggestions; but how about the constant current part of it all? Is there a "reference design" I should start from? Thanks!

Comment: Did you know that (if) 1 battery cell has 10Wh and your LED lamp is 10W then you can expect only 1h operation.

Comment: The Li-Ion battery has a capacity of 4000mAh, the Ityp. of the LEDs is 180mA (6.3W) and 360mA (12.6W). One hour at full brightness would be excellent for the use case (modelmaking).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer reg. calculating the "sensing resistor" for such boost ICs. In case of the latter one, it is in the application note "8.3.4 Current Program".

Now I only have to find a suitable inductor and hope that the suggested schematic will work.